# PHP - New numbered var for every object in array

Tags: php

I have the following scenario:

- Array with multiple waypoints
- Want a new variable for every waypoint
- Number of waypoints is not fixed

The array stores the address data for the waypoint like street, number, zip, town etc.

I can loop and print the output of the array in foreach loop like:

```
foreach ($waypoints as $waypoint) {
  echo $waypoint->street
  echo $waypoint->nb
  echo $waypoint->zip
  echo $waypoint->town
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, to get a new variable for each waypoint. E.g:

```
$wp1 = Data from waypoint 1
$wp2 = Data from waypoint 2
```

What I have tried:

```
$waypointCount = count($waypoints);    

for ($i = 1; $i < $waypointCount; $i++) {
  $wp[$i] = $waypoints->street.' '.$waypoints->nb.' '.$waypoints->zip.' '.$waypoints->town.' '.$waypoints->state;
}
```

My idea was to count the number of waypoints, set a new variable for each waypoint number and store the corresponding waypointdata in the new variable. I'm kinda stuck on how to create the $wp[i] variables and assign the data to it. Does it need to be a combination with a for and a foreach loop?

Looking for some help to get me on the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: …why tho…?! You already have an array of waypoints. You can access it as `$waypoints[0]` etc. What's the advantage of extracting that to individual variables?! (Hint: there is none.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to access the correct index of your `$waypoints` array in your loop. Also, make sure you start your loop with `$i = 0` or else you'll skip the first element.

```php
$waypointCount = count($waypoints);    

for ($i = 0; $i < $waypointCount; $i++) {
    $wp[$i] = $waypoints[$i]->street.' '.$waypoints[$i]->nb.' '.$waypoints[$i]->zip.' '.$waypoints[$i]->town.' '.$waypoints[$i]->state;
}
```

Comment: Totally missed the index there, now it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @InsaneTeddy Note that you're not creating variables `$wp1` etc. with this; you're creating an array `$wp`.

Comment: Yes, noticed that. But helped alot to solve my problem. Thank you for the replies.